# Exception creating an instance of http_client from cpprestsdk

Tags: c++, cpprest-sdk

I am using Visual Studio 2017. I have installed cpprestsdk (2.10.18) via vcpckg. I have done a first try according to https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/Getting-Started-Tutorial. Creating an instance of http_client throws an exception. The URI parameter seems to be correct. I have stripped the code down to this

```
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>

using namespace web::http::client;


int main() {

    http_client client(L"https://api.predic8.de");
    
    //....

    return 0;
}
```

Call stack:

```
>   cpprestsdk.exe!std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all() Line 221   C++
    cpprestsdk.exe!std::_String_alloc<std::_String_base_types<wchar_t,std::allocator<wchar_t> > >::_Orphan_all() Line 2024  C++
    cpprestsdk.exe!std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >::_Tidy_deallocate() Line 3986  C++
    cpprestsdk.exe!std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >::~basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >() Line 2460 C++
    cpprestsdk.exe!web::details::uri_components::~uri_components()  C++
    cpprestsdk.exe!web::uri::~uri() C++
    cpprestsdk.exe!main() Line 16   C++
    [External Code]
```

Build is Debug/x64 on a Windows 10 machine

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What was the exception?

Comment: it is a read access violation in line 221 (see call stack). The exception in thrown also in Release build, and also in 32bit builds. 

(my comment from yesterday was lost)